Magento Install Issue With MacBookPro
Services
  - nginx
  - composer 
  - mysql8
  - php8.1
  - redis

frontend and backend url is loading but not completely it is loading with broken like
skip content
below is the image


Try these Steps
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');

Permission issue so correct your permissiom first of all Command in your teminal
chmod -R 777 var pub
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush


Hi Kareem k .
it is not working still

here is my nginx config (is it fine)
pwd = /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/servers
server {
listen 80;
server_name demo.local;
root /usr/local/var/wwwdemo/pub;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000; # Ensure PHP-FPM is running on this port
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /.ht {
deny all;
}
}

It seems like there might be a typo in the path /usr/local/var/wwwdemo/pub should likely be /usr/local/var/www/demo/pub
